# Python typing of class instance attributes as copies of input args

Tags: python, class, variables, typing

When using typing in Python is it enough to do:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self, arg1: str, arg2: Union[str, int]):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

Or should everything be typed? Does the following have advantages and is it coding convention?

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self, arg1: str, arg2: Union[str, int]):
        self.arg1: str = arg1
        self.arg2: Union[str, int] = arg2
```

Comment: Since this is opinion-based, it seems this would be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. You can instead post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for advice, but make sure to comply with their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rules.

Comment: @costaparas it is not necessarily opinion based. Dependent upon certain official coding styles and typing documentation the answer may yet turn out to be definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how smart your type checker is, but I'd expect all current Python checkers to be able to infer from the first form what the types are for `arg1` and `arg2`.

Note that you *are* missing the return type annotation, `-> None`:

```py
class Something:
    def __init__(self, arg1: str, arg2: Union[str, int]) -> None:
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

See, for example, the [mypy documentation on *Class basics*](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html):

> The mypy type checker detects if you are trying to access a missing attribute, which is a very common programming error. For this to work correctly, instance and class attributes must be defined or initialized within the class. **Mypy infers the types of attributes**:
>
> ```
> class A:
>     def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
>         self.x = x  # Aha, attribute 'x' of type 'int'
>
> a = A(1)
> a.x = 2  # OK!
> a.y = 3  # Error: 'A' has no attribute 'y'
> ```

(bold emphasis mine).

I otherwise prefer to put instance attribute annotations at the class level, where they are more visible and so more easily read by other developers:

```py
class Something:
    arg1: str
    arg2: Union[str, int]

    def __init__(self, arg1: str, arg2: Union[str, int]) -> None:
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

Here, that leads to having to repeat yourself, but you could consider [using the `dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to avoid that.

Comment: Nice answer. Mypy allows you to omit the redundant `-> None` if at least one arg is typed. I have followed your lead..